# f:event triggered inside a h:panelGroup with rendered=false

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

I have `f:event` inside a `h:panelGroup` component with `rendered="false"` attribute. I want that the f:event listener should be triggered only when the block is rendered not otherwise.
My code as follows :

```
 <h:panelGroup rendered="false">
      <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{listRetriever.retrieveFollowers()}"/>
      <ui:repeat value="#{listRetriever.list}" var="person">
             #{person}<br/>
      </ui:repeat>
 </h:panelGroup>
```

How do I otherwise implement this correctly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is another event to manage component rendering `preRenderComponent`:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="false">
    <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{listRetriever.retrieveFollowers()}"/>
    <ui:repeat value="#{listRetriever.list}" var="person">
           #{person}<br/>
    </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGroup>
```

`preRenderViewEvent` is processed just before the entire view is rendered.

`preRenderComponentEvent` is processed during the view rendering, just before the component which includes `<f:event>` is rendered.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! Could you also clear as to how this is different than `preRender` view ?